# how do you increment a variable using a pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

My code is about implementing the function of Stack and Queue. If you're wondering why don't I use struct in my program that's because our instructor only allows us to use pointers and I'm a little bit confused using pointers. It's not yet finish, as much as possible I try to finish one function at a time instead of skipping to the next.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int container[5];
int len=0;
```

As I understand this part of my in function insert, "len" is suppose to change since it's incremented every time the function is use

```
int insert(int container[],int len)
{

    int i,j,content,*incre;
    incre=&len;

    for(i=*incre;i<*incre+1;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&content);

        container[i]=content;
    }
    (*incre)++;

}

int printcontent(int container[])
{
    int i;
    printf("Content of container:\n");

    for(i=0;i<len+1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",container[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

This part asks the user whether to add a content in the container or simply remove it. They can only add or remove one at a time.

```
int stack(int container[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        int choice;

        printf("What do you wanna do?\n");
        printf("1.Insert\n2.Pop\n3.isEmpty\n4.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
```

I checked the value of len it remains 0 instead of 1 when I first use insert.

```
        if (choice==1)
        {
            insert(container,len);
            printf("Value of len:%d\n",len);
            printcontent(container);

        }
        else if(choice==4)
        {
            break;
        }


    }


}

main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int choice;


        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1.Stack\n2.Queue\n3.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice==1)
        {.
            stack(container);
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misunderstood your question at first. Edited my answer below to actually give you something that might help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your `insert(...)` function does is that it takes the parameter `int len` by value. That means if you call `insert(...)` with the local variable `len` as an argument in `main(...)` or whereever - it actually copies the value of the local variable `len` to the argument variable `len` inside the `insert(...)` function. The variable `len` which is inside the `insert(...)` function is then local to the insert function. That does not change even if you're declaring a pointer named `incre` pointing to this `insert(...)`-local variable `len`.

Then the argument variable `len` is incremented - but due to the fact that it is a local variable of the `insert(...)` function you will not see the original local variable `len` (which is in `main(...)` e.g.) being changed.

If you want to pass the original `len` by reference instead of by value, you have to declare your function like this ...

```
int insert(int container[], int* len) { ... } // Using raw pointers
```

... or like this ...

```
int insert(int container[], int& len) { ... } // Using references
```

... and use it like that (depending on the decision above):

```
insert(container, &len); // With pointers
insert(container, len); // With references
```

Comment: We're talking about two different `len`s here. The one inside the `insert(...)` function (which is a parameter of `insert(...)` and the one you're passing as an argument to `insert(...)` when calling the function. The local argument variable inside `insert(...)` does get modified. The variable you passed when calling the function does not. Maybe it helpes if you read the part of a C++ guide explaining the pass-by-reference and pass-by-value semantics if you don't fully understand why this is happening. I hope I could at least clarify *that* this is happening. :)